# Loading Heavy Images on Pyagme Subset for Android

Tags: android, python-2.7, pygame

I am new to using Pygame for Android and I have been trying to convert my [This Game](https://github.com/pakhandi/Bit-Castle---Game) to an android game. Here I need to load around 6 images in one screen but when I try to load more than two images, the apk-application closes down abruptly (it works fine on PC). [Here is the complete code](https://github.com/pakhandi/Bit-Castle---Android/blob/master/main.py) of what I have done so far.

Is there any way I can load multiple images without making the game unstable for android?

Note : I am using Pygame Subset for Android to convert my .py to .apk

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, use [**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library for loading the images. I had the same problem with `OutOfMemory` exceptions, but this library solved my problem.

Download the Jar file and include it to your project, but before that make sure you read the documentation, it's very short and simple especially the IMAGE TRANSFORMATION part.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't find any way to use this library with pygame.. Can you give me more specific links or some examples?